# docker-compose error from VS2019 when try to add ports or depends_on

Tags: visual-studio, docker-compose

I'm newbee in docker. I have three .Net core 3.1 apps inside docker containers.
This is docker-compose file.

```
services:
  weather:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}weather
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Weather/Dockerfile

  apiclient:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}apiclient
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ApiClient/Dockerfile
 ports:
     - "5101:80"

  dbreader:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dbreader
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DBReader/Dockerfile
   # depends_on: - db

It not starting in VS2019 after i add ports or depends_on sections inside docker-compose file.

Error is System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.
Имя файла: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.Prerequisites.DockerForWindowsDriveSharingPrerequisite.<EvaluateAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.Prerequisites.DockerForWindowsDriveSharingPrerequisite.EvaluateAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   в Microsoft.Docker.Prerequisites.DockerForWindowsDriveSharingPrerequisite.<EvaluateAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Microsoft.Docker.Prerequisites.DockerCompositePrerequisite.<EvaluateAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Microsoft.Docker.BuildTasks.DockerBuildTask.<EvaluateBuildPrerequisitesAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Microsoft.Docker.BuildTasks.DockerBuildTask.<ExecuteAsync>d__30.MoveNext()

how to fix this?
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one should declare ports and depends_on like array in such manner:

```
  weather:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}weather
    depends_on: [db]
    ports:  ["5101:80"]
    environment:
     PROP1 : simple test value
     PROP2 : Y

    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Weather/Dockerfile

  apiclient:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}apiclient
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ApiClient/Dockerfile

  dbreader:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dbreader
    depends_on:  [db]
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DBReader/Dockerfile

  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: new_base
```